# How do I update data in the database in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, database, save, store

This is the code I have written so far:

**Here is my Controller that contains the edit and update function:**

```
public function edit($id){
        $post = Posts::find($id);

        return view('edit', compact('post'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id){
        $post = Posts::find($id);
            
        $validatedRequests = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|max:255|string|integer',
            'description' => 'required|max:255|string|integer',
            'price' => 'required|integer|max:255|'
        ]);

        $post->create($validatedRequests);
            
        return redirect('/Post/{{$post->id}}')->with('mssg', 'updates successfully');
    }
```

Here are my `Web.php` routes:

```
Route::get('/post/{id}/edit', [PostController::class, 'edit']);
Route::put('/post/{id}/update', [PostController::class, 'update']);
```

**Here is my blade(view) file**

```
<form method="POST" action="/post/{{$post->id}}/update">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    <label class="underline" for="title">change title:</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="title" value="{{$post->title}}"></input></br>
    <label class="underline" for="decsription">change description:</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="description" value="{{$post->description}}"></input></br>
    <label class="underline" for="price">change price:</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="price" value="{{$post->price}}"></input></br>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 2):

In your controller

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id)
{
   $post = Post::find($id);
   $post->title = $request->title;
   $post->description = $request->description;
   $post->price = $request->price;
   $post->save();
   return redirect('/Post/{{$post->id}}')->with('mssg', 'updates successfully');
}
```

Your Route

```
 Route::post('/post/{id}/edit', [PostController::class, 'edit']);
```

Your view

```
<form method="POST" action="/post/{{$post->id}}/edit">
@csrf
<label class="underline" for="title">change title:</label></br>
<input type="text" name="title" value="{{$post->title}}" required></input></br>
<label class="underline" for="decsription">change description:</label></br>
<input type="text" name="description" value="{{$post->description}}" required></input></br>
<label class="underline" for="price">change price:</label></br>
<input type="text" name="price" value="{{$post->price}}" required></input></br>

<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Controller should be:

```
public function edit(Request $request, Post $post) {
        $validatedRequests = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|max:255|string|integer',
            'description' => 'required|max:255|string|integer',
            'price' => 'required|integer|max:255|'
        ]);    

        $post->update([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'price' => $request->price    
        ]);    

        $post->save();

        return redirect('/Post/{{$post->id}}')->with('mssg', 'updates successfully'); 
}
```

Your Route

```
 Route::post('/post/{post:id}/edit', [PostController::class, 'edit'])->name('post.update');
```

Your View  should be:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('post.update', ['post'=> $post->id])}}">
@csrf
<label class="underline" for="title">change title:</label></br>
<input type="text" name="title" value="{{$post->title}}" required></input></br>
<label class="underline" for="description">change description:</label></br>
<input type="text" name="description" value="{{$post->description}}" required></input></br>
<label class="underline" for="price">change price:</label></br>
<input type="text" name="price" value="{{$post->price}}" required></input></br>

<input type="submit" value="submit">
```